# "No more someone doing something" meaning

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

By the phrase **no more** we mean **Someone doesn't want something anymore.**
Eg:

> Son: Mom, I am going to play cricket.

Mom: **No more cricket!** Your exams are very close.

The same way, can I say:

> **No more doing something: No more playing cricket.**
>
> **No more someone doing something: No more students playing cricket.**

In the last sentence only "students" are being prohibited to play cricket.

Are all the the three forms correct?

Comment: *No more* does ***not*** necessarily mean "someone doesn't want something anymore." Depending on context, it's either a simple statement of fact or an imperative (command). But it doesn't say anything about *why* there should be no more of something.

Answer (score 1):

Your last example could be interpreted as: there are no more students playing cricket, either because playing cricket has been prohibited or the cricket-playing students have left. I think you are looking for: no more playing cricket for(the)students or no more playing cricket for you (your second example).

Comment: "Mamma called the doctor and doctor said: No more kitten jumping on the bed." Is this part of children rhyme grammartical?

Comment: same thing, the kitten is no longer allowed to jump on the bed.